# C# const int[] error

Tags: c#, constants

I want to declare constant integer array in my code.

**Code C#:**

```
namespace example
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow 
    {
        public const int[] ai_pavyzdys = { 186, 186 };
    }
}
```

> I get an error:
>   *Error    1   'KET3._2.MainWindow.ai_pavyzdys' is of type 'int[]'. A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized
>   with
>   null. C:\Users\Armandas\Desktop\viskas_programavimo\KET3.2\MainWindow.xaml.cs 22  42  KET3.2*

How can I fix it to declare `const int[]`?

Comment: You should use `readonly`

Comment: but then I can change the value(with readonly)

Comment: `const` is for **compile-time** constants. This is a **runtime** constant.